# Promag Card Reader PHP Accessing

Tags: php, smartcard, pcsc

I have promag 310 card reader. It is connect to PC with com port. I want to access card ID with PHP xampp in windows platform. I add `php_pcsc.dll` to extension folder. And I update `php.ini` with it. then I wrote this code:

```php
$context = scard_establish_context();
$readers = scard_list_readers($context);

print_r($readers);

// then when you have your card reader's identity from $readers

$connection = scard_connect($context, 'YOUR CARD READER HERE');
$response   =  scard_transmit($connection, 'pdu string');
```

But PHP returns:

```php
resource(2) of type (PC/SC Context) NULL
```

So I did not access card reader. How can I access card ID with PHP? Does anybody have any idea to achieve this situation?

Thank You.

Comment: Small formatting issues

Comment: Are you sure you have a PCSC driver installed for your serial reader? If you don't, this is the most likely obstacle matching your description.

Comment: I can access card reader mifare demo software which is coded by .Net. I can get card number by using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am the developer of the PHP extension for accessing smartcards, I can say you are doing everything right. It seems your card reader is not supported. I use an Omnikey 5321 and SCM SCL011 for accessing smart cards and they work just fine.

Since you are using Windows I can not try check what possibly goes wrong.

Comment: Hey, wait... I believe it fails on creating the $context already. I will need to investigate a little bit more to figure out what is wrong. Normally you should get the context regardless of the operating system. I will try to get it running on a Windows machine as soon as possible.

Comment: After some investigation I believe that your card reader is not PCSC compliant. I could not reproduce your problem. I think your reader uses a special protocol for communication and the .Net demo for Mifare does not use the winscard API.

Comment: Hi, you are right. My card reader is not compatible for pcsc extension. I found python script and I could access card id. Thanks for all help...

Comment: @erkunt can you elaborate with this python script please. Where can I find it?